# How do you print to a printer directly using Python 3.3.2 on Windows?

Tags: python, pyqt

I am struggling to find any examples of code to get data in Python to print to a printer. Any examples I find either use win32api (which I can't seem to get installed for Python 3.3.2) or just outright won't work.

The documentation I've looked at is all jumbled up to me as I am programming using PyQt in Monkey Studio, and any Qt documentation for printing seems to only work for regular Qt.

Does anyone have any simple working code that can print to a printer plugged in via USB or over wifi using Python and/or PyQt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are going to need to get win32api to work as that is the only way you will be able to interface with the windows system in order to get information about the printers available to your local device. What seems to be the issue when installing win32api? This resource here is helpful for when you do manage to install it http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/print.html. You may need to find binaries for the library and install them using pip.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you are trying to print but i use the code below to print out values from my QTableView. You can modify to suit your code since you didnt give us any of it.

```
def printing(self):
    printer = QtGui.QPrinter(QtGui.QPrinter.ScreenResolution)
    dialog = QtGui.QPrintPreviewDialog(printer)
    view = PrintView()
    view.setModel(self.tableView1.model())
    dialog.paintRequested.connect(view.print_)
    dialog.exec_()


class PrintView(QtGui.QTableView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(PrintView, self).__init__()
        self.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        self.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)

    def print_(self, printer):
        self.resize(printer.width(), printer.height())
        self.render(printer)
```